# Will removing a HTML section block from my all website pages, affects SEO and my website rank?

Tags: seo, html, performance, optimization

So I have a hidden HTML section block that is heavy and requires multiple HTTP requests, which slowing my website page speed load.

So I am trying to implement a **lazyloading** methodology for this specific section to only render after someone clicking on the [SHOW] button.
I want to know if removing this entire HTML section from my web pages will cause a problem for Google or any other bots and will damage my rank? or not?

Thanks.

Comment: TBC: the HTML block contains several links to some other pages. those links only exist in this HTML block.

Answer (score 1):

- Whether it will affect your ranking, depends on if most of your content is there, and of course on whether google wants it to affect it or not. So there is no yes or no answer to this part.
- The problem I suspect it will cause is, if you are using a lot of javascript, google will put it on a "check later". What it means is - google goes to a webpage and scans it; They index all the relevant HTML, some css and some javascript, HOWEVER, javascript takes a lot more processing power from the googlebot than HTML. So what Google does is index the HTML as soon as they can, while they
  put the javascript in a long list of other javascripts that needs to
  be executed and only when they reach to your javascript they will
  index what it generates (and with Google, even this is not certain).

The bottom line is, I wouldn't recommend removing the html and moving it to a complicated script, unless it REALLY REALLY slows down the site.